# Magento Get Product SELECTED ATTRIBUTE only?

Tags: magento, attributes, product

Hi i'm working on an external application thats shows all the ordered items on a magento store.

The query that display the ordered product attribute is this :

```
   select group_concat(distinct(b.value) separator '<br/>') from catalog_product_entity_varchar a , eav_attribute_option_value b  , eav_attribute c 
    where a.value = b.option_id
    and c.attribute_id =  a.attribute_id
    and c.is_user_defined = 1
    and a.entity_id = PRODUCT_ID
```

This is for the attributes with type VARCHAR , i use the same query to get attributes of int and text. I just change the table name from catalog_product_entity_varchar to catalog_product_entity_int and catalog_product_entity_text.

The problem that i have is that i GET all the product attributes , manufacturer , supplier... and due to the fact that we got many stores i dont want to retrieve all the additional attributes with an additional sql where clause!

Any solution to get only selected attributes?

Comment: you can always select from flat  product table

Comment: Flat product table shows informations concerning the product but not all attributes values

an example of what i'm looking for , for example we got an iPhone as a configurable Product.
it has 3 related simple product 
First :  Color : Black - Model : 3
Second :  Color : White - Model : 4
Third : Color : Gray - Model : 5
The client did purchase the third one
So i want to get this : iPhone - Gray/5
Instead i get the whole attributes (supplier , manufacturer and some additional attributes)

Comment: well if you need purchases then select from order related flat tables instead

Answer (score 0):

The below will grab the collection in PHP.  You just need to change the Attribute that you select on.  By adding the ->addOrderedQty, it allows the ability to get the ordered qty.  Now I understand that you are using an external application.  The reason that I post this is that you can load the Mage.php into your application and use this directly or you can just run this once and watch for the query in your database and then use that query to accomplish what you are looking to.

```
$visibility = array( 
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, 
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG 
                  ); 

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') 
                              ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
                              ->addOrderedQty() 
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility) 
                              ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```